# QuerySet object has no attribute 'user' on Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

I cannot serialize a model to get results while performing requests on Django Rest Framework.

#### models.py

```
class Karfarma(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='karfarma', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.TextField(max_length=11)
    validation_number = models.TextField(max_length=5, blank=True, default=None)
    phone_number = models.TextField(max_length=10, blank=True, default=None)
    datetime_join_persian = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

#### serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

#### views.py

```
class UserList(APIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get(self, request):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here's the reduced version of the error which I get when I perform the request:

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'.

Comment: can you add `urls.py` to your question, and probably `views.py` as well. I don't understand the link between your serializer and your model...

Comment: @LaurentS I edit my question

Comment: try serializer = UserSerializer(users,many=True)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Whenever you are trying to pass a queryset to a serializer always pass it with `UserSerializer(users,many=True)`. If you just want to pass a single user object you can use `User.objects.get(some_attribue=something)` and then pass that object to the serializer without the `many=True` flag.

Comment: It helped me solve my problem. Thank you sir @Aniruddha Bhondwe

Comment: So, we have to use many=True in views too!
This simple suggestion solved my problem, Thanks

Answer (score -7):

finally I found what was wrong 
view was the problem when ever you want to get list of objects you should pass argument `many=True` to the serializer.
the problem was this

Comment: Did you seriously accept your answer which is just a bad copy of a previously posted correct answer?