# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

```
#models
class Student(models.Model):
firstname =  models.CharField(max_length=100,default='ll')
lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='fewf')
id_code = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=0,unique=True)
melli = models.CharField(max_length=30,default=0,unique=True)
personal_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=studentFile)
major = models.ForeignKey(Major, on_delete=models.PROTECT,default=0)
date_of_start = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

def __str__(self):
    return self.id_code

#views
class loginView(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    data = request.data
    melli = data.get('melli')
    id_code = data.get('id_code')
    student = Student.objects.filter(id_code=id_code,melli=melli)
    if not student.exists():
       return Response('error')
    serializer = StudentSerializer(student,data=data)
    serializer.is_valid()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

when i try to submit a post request i was excepted to recive a response but i got an error. how can i solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QuerySet object has no attribute 'user' on Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734903/queryset-object-has-no-attribute-user-on-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 1):

You serialize a *collection* of elements, so you should work with `many=True`:

```
serializer = StudentSerializer(student,data=data, many=True)
```

in case you want to only work with a single object, you need to retrieve a *single* object, not a collection of objects, for example with [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) instead of [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter).

Comment: thanks bro, this one solved my issue, but cause i need to retrive a single element, i must set many to false

Answer (score 1):

`Model.filter` returns a *queryset*, which is like a *list of models*, rather than a specific model.  Instead, you should use `get`, which returns a single model instance:

```
student = Student.objects.get(id_code=id_code,melli=melli)
```

If you intend on there being more than 1 student in this specific query, you can add `many=True` to your serializer instead:

```
serializer = StudentSerializer(student,data=data, many=True)
```

Comment: hhmm, I have done exactly this; `serializer = mySerializer(queryset, data=data, many=True)` but `is_valid()` still returns `*** AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'`

Comment: ah, `to_internal_value` needs to be modified as suggested here https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/issues/68 in my case