# AttributeError Implementing First Serializer: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I've just built a Item (product) model for my project's eCommerce page, an ItemDetailsView which returns individual items and an ItemApiView which is meant to create/retrieve/update/delete. When I make a get request to get ItemApiView I expect it to return a full list of items in my database. However, I am getting the following error:

`` AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `ItemSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance. Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'. ``

"name" is a field in my Item model. Here is the full model:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    """
    Item that can be purchased
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", default="images/default.png")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    discount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"
        ordering = ("-created",)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("store:product_detail", args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
```

Here is the ItemApiView. Only the "Get" method corresponds to my specific problem but I included the full view because I am open to critiques on the put/post/delete methods which I have not yet tested:

```
class ItemApiView(APIView):
    """
    API endpoint to retrieve, create and update
    """

    @limits(settings.RATE_LIMIT_REQUESTS, settings.RATE_LIMIT_DURATION)
    def get(self, request):
        """Return all items"""

        print("request", request)

        try:
            items = Item.objects.all()
            serialized_data = ItemSerializer(items)
        except:
            return Response({"message": "No items exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        return Response(serialized_data.data)

    @limits(settings.RATE_LIMIT_REQUESTS, settings.RATE_LIMIT_DURATION)
    def put(self, request):
        """Update item info"""
        item_id = request.data["item_id"]

        try:
            item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id),
            id=request.data["id"],
            name=request.data["name"],
            price=request.data["price"],
            is_active=request.data["is_active"],
            description=request.data["description"],
            discount=request.data["discount"],
            image=request.data["image"],
            quantity=request.data["quantity"],
            category=request.data["category"],
        except Item.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        if item.name != name:
            item.name = name
        elif item.description != description:
            item.description = description
        elif item.price != price:
            item.price = price
        elif item.is_active != is_active:
            item.is_active = is_active
        elif item.discount != discount:
            item.discount = discount
        elif item.quantity != quantity:
            item.quantity = quantity
        elif item.category != category:
            item.category = category

        item.save()

        return Response(ItemSerializer(item).data)

    def delete(self, request):
        """Delete item"""

        item_id = request.data["item_id"]

        try:
            item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
        except Item.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        item.delete()

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @limits(settings.RATE_LIMIT_REQUESTS, settings.RATE_LIMIT_DURATION)
    def post(self, request):
        """Create item"""

        item = Item.objects.create(
            id=request.data["id"],
            name=request.data["name"],
            price=request.data["price"],
            is_active=request.data["is_active"],
            description=request.data["description"],
            discount=request.data["discount"],
            image=request.data["image"],
            quantity=request.data["quantity"],
            category=request.data["category"]

        )

        Event.objects.create(
            user=user,
            event_type=Event.ITEM_CREATE,
            payload={
                "id": item.id,
                "name": item.name,
                "price": item.price,
                "is_active": item.is_active,
                "description": item.description,
                "discount": item.discount,
                "image": item.image,
                "quantity": item.quantity,
                "category": item.category,
            },
        )

        return Response(ItemSerializer(item).data)
```

and finally here is the ItemSerializer:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Item Serializer
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QuerySet object has no attribute 'user' on Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734903/queryset-object-has-no-attribute-user-on-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 1):

try to add many=True, when creating list serializer

```
class ItemApiView(APIView):
    ...
    def get(self, request):
        ...

        try:
            items = Item.objects.all()
            serialized_data = ItemSerializer(items, many=True)
        ...
```

Comment: You saved my evening :)
It works without many=True on my local instance, but not on the server